# Provider State is lost on hot reload - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I'm trying to add provider to save the fact that my user is logged in, and i see the changes from my provider after the login has succeded, switching from loginscreen to home.
But if i do a hot-reload, i'm losing the state of the provider and back to the loginscreen.

So i tried to do a basic tutorial i saw on youtube to save a counter value but same problem, the value of the counter is erased on a hot reload.

I have no clue of where the problem can be.

Here is the code for the counter

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:default_app/counter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(
          create: (_) => Counter(),
          child: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page')),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counter = Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times 23:',
            ),
            Consumer<Counter>(
              builder: (context, counter, child) => Text(
                '${counter.value}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: counter.increment,
        tooltip: 'Increment text',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**Counter.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int value = 0;

  void increment() {
    value++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have try your code,  data not reset after `r Hot reload.` , data is reset after `R Hot restart.`.  But it is the design.

Comment: I'm testing it on visual studio code, and on chome (not on emulator). and i stil lahve the problem.
What do you mean by the design ?

Comment: oh, I only test is on emulator.   in emulator,  Hot restart will reset data, Hot reload will not reset the data.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the hot-reload reloads the entire app from scratch. Therefore all values are losts. So, for this you'll need an external source to know if the user is logged in or not. For this, you may try storing the session status using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) or [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), and when the user opens the app, load the value, so you can actually preserve the session status.

Comment: I was using shared preference to store the JWT only, i thought the state was persistent.
so I have to write a function that detect if i have a jwt in storage and then update the provider state  ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And bc you are storing a JWT I think that Hive would be a better option than SharedPreferences, given it's more secure. I would also think if storing the JWT is actually a good idea when it comes to security concerns.

Comment: I'll look into Hive then.
whats is the best way to store it ? cookies ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the navigator, the state is lost when the browser refresh.
The workaround is to save the state with Hive for example.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you perform a hot reload, Flutter rebuilds your widget tree. If the `Counter` Provider is being recreated in this process (for example, if it's created within the build method of a widget), its state will be reset. Make sure your Provider is declared at the top level of your app (usually in the main.dart).

From this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

to this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: CounterProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
void main() {
```

runApp(MyApp());
}

To

```
void main() {
```

runApp(

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
  ],
  child: const MyApp(),
),
```

);
}

as stated on the provider documentation example
https://pub.dev/packages/provider/example